# ffmpeg - trying to add a reversed section of original video to the back (boomerang effect)

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a ffmpeg command as follows which basically scales the video down to 720p. Now i want to add a section to my command which will make a concatination of the video but in reverse. So that the video will also be in a loop like this:

0s -> 10s -> 0s

original command:

```
ffmpeg -ss 0.0 -to 10.0 -i in.mp4 -filter_complex "fps=15,scale=720:-1" -y out.mp4
```

Command after my edits:

```
ffmpeg -ss 0.0 -to 10.0 -i in.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]fps=15,scale=720:-1,reverse,fifo[r];[0:v][r] concat=n=2:v=1 [v]" -map "[v]" -y out.mp4
```

When executing im getting following erorrs:

```
Parsed_concat_4 @ 0x7feb89d01d40] Input link in1:v0 parameters (size 720x1280, SAR 1:1) do not match the corresponding output link in0:v0 parameters (1080x1920, SAR 1:1)
[Parsed_concat_4 @ 0x7feb89d01d40] Failed to configure output pad on Parsed_concat_4
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid argument
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:1
```

I'm very new into coding advanced ffmpeg commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `Input link in1:v0 parameters (size 720x1280, SAR 1:1) do not match
>   the corresponding output link in0:v0 parameters (1080x1920, SAR 1:1)`

The [concat](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#concat) filter requires all inputs to be the same size and aspect ratio, but you are attempting to concatenate different sizes and aspect ratios. To fix this you can also scale the other segments to be concatenated.

You can use the [split](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#split) filter to efficiently duplicate outputs from other filters, then reverse one of the duplicates, and finally concat everything together.

```
ffmpeg -to 10 -i in.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]fps=15,scale=720:-1,split=3[begin][mid][end];[mid]reverse[r];[begin][r][end]concat=n=3:v=1:a=0[v]" -map "[v]" out.mp4
```